# Returning from a Comparable returning generic java.util.function.Function

Tags: java, generics, method-reference

I have a method which returns a `java.util.Function<A, T>` where `T` is generic type. I need `T` to be an instance of `Comparable<T>`. Trying to return a method reference in `getFunction()` I get the error:

```
Error:(9, 16) java: incompatible types: bad return type in method reference
    java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to T
```

Here is an MCVE:

```java
import java.util.function.Function;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getFunction(true).apply(new A(5)));
    }

    static <T extends Comparable<T>> Function<A, T> getFunction(boolean b) {
        if (b) return A::getX;
        else return A::getRandomString;
    }
}

class A {
    private Integer x;

    A(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    String getRandomString() {
        return "Hello Stack Overflow";
    }
}
```

I've tried using the wildcard return type `Function<A, ?>` but then I cannot call `compareTo()`.
Is there any way to return a `Comparable` from such a method with type safety?

Comment: It makes no sense to have a generic `T` here if you **always** have an `Integer` returned.

Comment: @luk2302 It won't always be an `Integer`.

Comment: But it sure is now. The compiler will never accept this. You let the caller decide what `T` is and then you always return an `Integer`. Unless you show where you are trying to go with this there is not much we can do.

Comment: Do you just want to return a `Function<A, Comparable<?>>`?

Comment: @luk2302 Edited

Comment: What happens if your call `Function<A, String> function = getFunction(true)`? That's why the code fails to compile.

Comment: That is unfortunately never going to work. The compiler will never be able to determine the result type of `getFunction`. And you will never be able to call `compareTo` on the result. How do you expect the code to handle a `String` result which you then `compareTo(5)` which you are not allowed since `compareTo` only accepts `T` or `String` in this case?